# Text notes randomly enlarge in Preview pdf files

Tags: pdf

I like to edit my pdf documents and add notes (I'm studying Russian). But sometimes I'll add a note, and then open the file on a later day, and the text will have become much larger, or sometimes have completely disappeared.

This is random as far as I can tell. Sometimes it happens the next day, and sometimes everything is stable for weeks.

What is causing this, and how can I fix the problem? Sometimes I lose very important notes because of this problem.

**In the screenshots below the once blue text has, for no reason, enlarged and become black. Sometimes all the text will even dissapear from the screen entirely, or half will be in some no-man's land off the edge of the screen.**

[image: The text in black ws the name size as the text in blue when I addd the note]

[image: The text in black has for no reason enlarged and changed colors]

Comment: Does adobe reader have 5he same problem?

Comment: @TomGewecke I have never tried Adobe, but overall I much prefer Preview. It doesn't happen with all pdf documents. It tends to happen with ones that have clickable links in the table of contents.

Comment: I prefer preview, sorry